# Obtain actual browser URL in PHP

Tags: php

I need to retrieve the actual URL that the user see's in their browser. I have an Ajax request running at page load. Hence, the regular `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` expression returns the request URL of the Ajax request instead of the actual URL in the browser.

Any idea how to get this?

Comment: print_r($_SERVER); something there may help

Comment: why do you think you need that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could pass it up from javascript in your ajax request, using `window.location.href`.

Also, it's likely that `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will contain the browser's current location.

Comment: Thx for the reply. The need for browser URL is elsewhere within the code and hence passing the same via Ajax is not an option. The HTTP_REFERER does work for me. However, are there any possible inconsistencies due to which the value return could be different?

Comment: Most browsers will set the referer properly, but they are not required to do so and there's no guarantee it will be set. If you're making an ajax request, there should be no reason you can't add a name/value pair to the posted variables (or even in the query string) that holds the proper URL.

Comment: Well in that case I would have to look at modifying the code and not depend on PHP server vars. Thx for explaining this.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`.  This might work, not 100% sure though.

Comment: This works for me. However, are there any possible inconsistencies due to which the value return could be different.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with server-side code, as there is no server-side variable that refers to what the client sees. The only thing you CAN see (and then again, it depends on the browser the user's using, some don't pass this info) is the HTTP_REFERRER variable. This however, is only set when a page calls another, not when users first access your site.

See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) for more details.

A possible solution however, might be to use javascript function to send the browser's top URL to the server using an AJAX query, and to fire it client-side whenever a user loads the pages) you want to get this info for.

Edit: Damn, too slow, already answered!

Answer (score 1):

Pass a hidden input that has the browser value set with your ajax request.  Unless someone is being malicious, it should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

If you do an Ajax-request, you could pass the address available through Javascripts `window.location.href` variable as a POST-variable with the request.

With jQuery it would be something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'your-url.php',
  type: "POST",
  data: { url: window.location.href },
  success: function (data) {
     // Do something on success
  }
});
```

With such a request you could access the URL on the server-side with a simple:

```
<?php  
   $url = $_POST["url"];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actual Website Link in php

```
   <?php 
          echo $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Server-side languages can't see what happens **after** they've rendered and outputted the page.